# 'Can't play this video' error when playing mp4 with video view?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have the following code

```
  val path = "android.resource://" + activity?.packageName + "/" + R.raw.body_video
  val uri = Uri.parse(path)
  videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
  videoView.start()
```

but on loading the view i get this

[image]

The path all seems to be correct, so im unsure what could be wrong. This asset works on our iOS app so the file is ok

Answer (score -1):

The way you are getting the id from resource folder (raw) is wrong. Try will following code it will work.

In Java

```
     // To get files from any resource folder (eg: raw, drawable, etc.)
     // Use the resource id
     int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier(file_name_without_extension,  "raw", getPackageName());

     // URI formation
     String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + rawId;

     // Set the URI to play video file
     videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
     videoView.start()
```

Kotlin Activity

```
    // To get files from any resource folder (eg: raw, drawable, etc.) 
    //Use the resource id
     val rawId = resources.getIdentifier(file_name_without_extension, "raw", packageName)

    // URI formation
    val path = "android.resource://$packageName/$rawId"
    
    // Set the URI to play video file
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path))
    videoView.start()
```

Kotlin Fragment @Update

```
// To get files from any resource folder (eg: raw, drawable, etc.) Use the resource id
val packageNameValue = activity!!.packageName
val rawId = activity!!.resources.getIdentifier(file_name_without_extension, "raw", packageNameValue)

// URI formation
val path = "android.resource://$packageNameValue/$rawId"

// Set the URI to play video file
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path))
videoView.start()
```

Comment: This didnt work, i tried         val rawId = resources.getIdentifier("body_video", "raw", activity?.packageName)
        val path = "android.resource://$activity?.packageName/$rawId"

Comment: its just the same code as in my OP broken down a slight different way...

Comment: @jwarris91 i have checked in my device it is working fine. Can you please show me the exact error.

Comment: Please also check the 'file_name_without_extension' it should be valid without any special character.

Comment: If it is not working please try in in real device instead of emulator.

Comment: theres no more to show than what i already have, i also dont have a real device to try on

Comment: your code is also for an activity not in a fragement, so theres slight difference with what my situation is

Comment: @jwarris91i have updated the answer and added the code for fragment. Please check it.  It will work.

Comment: still doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: @jwarris91 Please try in real device.